Writing a code in python to find kth largest element from an array. Is this code right or this can have flaws?
def k_large(self, k):
    n = len(self)
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(i+1, n):
            if self[i] < self[j]:
                self[i],self[j] = self[j],self[i]
    return self[:k]

I tried running this and this returns the kth largest elements asked for but I am not sure if this might have flaws or not.

I think you may be confused about what the self keyword is used for. Either that, or you should [edit] your question to include the class that contains this method.

@JRiggles It seems like this class is a subclass of list, since it's performing lots of list operations on self.

self[:k] is the first k elements. The kth largest is self[k-1] (assuming there are no duplicates).

@Barmar sure, but we're always better off not guessing

The simplest way is to sort the list then return element [k-1]

@Barmar that's kind of what this code is doing, except it's using a really slow (Bubble) sort and returning more than one element.

This question is too broad for Stack Overflow. For improving working code, you can ask on [codereview.se] instead, but first I recommend taking their tour and reading their How to Ask page.

If it helps, there are existing questions about this task on SO, like Get the second largest number in a list in linear time

@MarkRansom Not bubble but exchange.

@nocomment I keep forgetting that Bubble sort only exchanges adjacent elements.  Thanks for the correction.

The identifier self is normally used in methods to refer to the actual class instance the method is being called on. So let's use the name lst (or some identifier of your choice other than self) instead.
You appear to be sorting the passed list in reverse order (from greatest value to lowest) and then returning the first k elements, i.e. the k largest elements. The sorting looks like it works but it is certainly not an efficient algorithm and there are faster ways of doing this (e.g. the built-in sorted function). Do you consider inefficiency a "flaw"? What I would consider a flaw is that you are modifying the passed list. There is nothing about the function specification that suggests that this side-effect should be acceptable (the sorted function will return a sorted copy of the original list). So you should first make a copy of the list and sort that.
The question title states that you want to find the kth largest element, i.e. a single element, but you are currently returning the k largest elements. This is a flaw. Therefore, replace:
    return self[:k]

with:
    return self[k - 1]

Anyway, that's what I would interpret the kth element to mean regardless of whether there are duplicates or not. If duplicates are to be considered, then you need to first remove duplicate values from your list copy before sorting. After doing so, there may not even be k elements left. So you should always verify that the original list and the list with duplicates removed, if that is required, have k elements.
It would also be useful for you to review PEP 8 – Style Guide for Python Code.

Maybe I'm oversimplifying the ask, but is there a reason why this wouldn't work?
def k_large(values,k):
    return sorted(values, reverse=True)[k-1]

